# SBT Verify Error caused by multiple protobuf 2/3 dependencies in spite of shading

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-bigtable, spotify-scio

I am struggling with Verify Errors with this below sample project using Scio/Bigtable/HBase. The dependency tree requires protobuf version (2.5, 2.6.1, 3.0, 3.1) and seems to default to 3.2. I used the shading component of `sbt-assembly`, not sure I am right with it.

My **build.sbt**:

```
name := "scalalab"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.spotify" %% "scio-core" % "0.3.2",
  "com.google.cloud.bigtable" % "bigtable-hbase-1.2" % "0.9.2",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.5",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.5",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.3"
)

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

My **Main.scala**:

```
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.Adapters
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.read.DefaultReadHooks
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val scan = new Scan
    scan.setMaxVersions()
    scan.addFamily("family".getBytes)
    scan.setRowPrefixFilter("prefix".getBytes)

    val builder = Adapters.SCAN_ADAPTER.adapt(scan, new DefaultReadHooks)

    System.out.println(builder)
  }
}
```

outputs to:

```
scalalab git:(master) ? java -cp .:target/scala-2.11/scalalab-assembly-1.0.jar Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    shadeio/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/AppendAdapter.adapt(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Operation;)Lshadeio/bigtable/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$Builder; @8: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'shadeio/bigtable/v2/ReadModifyWriteRowRequest$Builder' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'shadeio/bigtable/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$Builder' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @8
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'shadeio/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/AppendAdapter', 'org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Operation' }
    stack: { 'shadeio/bigtable/v2/ReadModifyWriteRowRequest$Builder' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b c000 28b6 00a0 b0

        at shadeio.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.Adapters.<clinit>(Adapters.java:40)
        at Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
        at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The dependency issue is quit a pain for the Cloud Bigtable HBase client.  We'll be fixing it in the next release.  To fix your current problem, import "bigtable-hbase" instead of "bigtable-hbase-1.2"

Also, I would suggest using the latest version of the client is possible, which is 0.9.7.1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With your dependency replacement, Adapters is no longer importable...

Comment: Ugh... Adapters is moved to a different package, and so do the protobuf objects.  Sorry about that.  You can use `bigtable-hbase` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, gets another error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shadeio.bigtable.v2.RowRange$Builder.setStartKeyClosed(Lshadeio/bigtable/repackaged/com/google/protobuf/ByteString;)Lshadeio/bigtable/v2/RowRange$Builder`. This may be related to a conflit in 2+ versions of protobuf.

Comment: The "repacka‌ged" version of the protos is in `bigtable-hbase-1.2` and `bigtable-hbase-shaded-for-dataflow`.  You probably should use `bigtable-hbase`.

Comment: FYI, tomorrow (hopefully), we'll release a new version of the client that has an HBase Beam connector.

Answer (score 0):

Scio has a bigtable artifact, which you can include via:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.spotify" %% "scio-core" % "0.3.2",
  "com.spotify" %% "scio-bigtable" % "0.3.2"
)
```

Usually, there is no need for the other dependencies to use Bigtable, in fact they might cause issues.

Make sure to then import bigtable package via:

```
import com.spotify.scio.bigtable._
```

Check this [BigtableExample](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-examples/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/examples/extra/BigtableExample.scala).

Side note you might want to give `sbt-pack` a try instead of `sbt-assembly` to fully leverage artifact caching. For an example of sbt setup check the template [here](https://github.com/spotify/scio-template.g8).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My post was not very clear, but in the above code, I used the Bigtable client outside of scio. Using the bigtable client through Scio does work with your dependency.